# How to change j2me netbean 6.9 simulator

Tags: java, java-me, simulator

How to change j2me netbean 6.9 simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Java Platform and add the new platform. Then select the new SDK location and add it. See [how to install the Nokia S60 SDK in NetBeans for J2ME development](http://www.javamidlet.com/2008/07/12/how-to-install-the-nokia-s60-sdk-in-netbeans-for-j2me-development.html). And see here, [configuring netbeans](http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-AD2184E8-AD98-4B77-A9EB-DBC366953DC6.html).